# Error Cannot Initialize a Parameter of Type 'int *' with an rvalue type of 'int'

Tags: c++, macos, opencv

I'm writing a project in OpenCV 2.4.9 using Mac OSX 10.9.  I have been getting this strange error, detailed in title, and can't seem to figure it out.  Any help is appreciated, thanks!
AppDelegate.m File-

```
- (IBAction)manual:(id)sender {

    cv::VideoCapture cap(0);

    if ( !cap.isOpened()) {
        std::cout << "Cannot open the web cam" << std::endl;
    }

    cv::namedWindow("Control", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cv::namedWindow("Manual Calibration", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    self.LH = 0;
    self.HH = 179;
    self.LS = 0;
    self.HS = 255;
    self.LV = 0;
    self.HV = 255;
    //int counter = 0;

//Error is here
    cv::createTrackbar("Low Hue- ", "Control", self.LH, 179);
    cv::createTrackbar("High Hue- ", "Control", self.HH, 179);
    cv::createTrackbar("Low Saturation- ", "Control", self.LS, 255);
    cv::createTrackbar("High Saturation- ", "Control", self.HS, 255);
    cv::createTrackbar("Low Value- ", "Control", self.LV, 255);
    cv::createTrackbar("High Value- ", "Control", self.HV, 255);


    while (true){
        cv::Mat testInitial;
        cap.read(testInitial);
        cv::Mat testHSV;
        cv::Mat test;
        cvtColor(testInitial, testHSV, CV_BGR2HSV);
        cv::inRange(testHSV,cv::Scalar((self.LH), (self.LS), (self.LV)),cv::Scalar((self.HH), (self.HS), (self.HV)),test);
        cv::imshow("Test", test);
        cv::waitKey(10);
    }
}
```

AppDelegate.h file-

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
    IBOutlet NSMenu *statusMenu;
    NSStatusItem *statusItem;
    NSImage *statusImage;
    NSImage *statusHighlightImage;
}

//Action
- (IBAction)start:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)manual:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)automatic:(id)sender;

@property (nonatomic, assign) int LH;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int HH;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int LS;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int HS;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int LV;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int HV;

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're supposed to pass the *address* of an integer variable to createTrackBar.

```
int hue = 17; // start value
cv::createTrackbar("Low Hue- ", "Control", &hue, 179);
```

Comment: but i want to have the hue values be logged

Comment: where's the problem with that ?

Comment: nvm I understand what you mean.  sorry i was delirious at a hackathon